# How to redirect user to another internal page?

Tags: javascript, redirect, parse-platform

After creating the record, the user would be redirected to an internal page.

```
"redirect to home.html"
```

I've tried, add the code under "Sucess" but had no success :(
How to be redirected after register or log in?

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

With the above code only works after pressing F5

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       Parse.initialize("UWkFSQ1DY.......", "mgI77........");
       var Post = Parse.Object.extend("Post");

       $("#signup").submit(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();

         var username = $("#signup-username").val();
         var pass = $("#signup-password").val();
         var email = $("#signup-email").val();

         var user = new Parse.User();
         user.set("username", username);
         user.set("password", pass);
         user.set("email", email);

         user.signUp(null, {
           sucess: function(user){
            window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
           }, error: function(user, error){
             console.log("signup error:"+error.message);
           }
         });
       });
  </script>
```

Comment: Are you sure the `sucess` function is being called? Maybe put an alert in there to check?

Comment: Yes it is called, already used alerts and console.log and registration is being completed!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code itself. If I just open the console and type in `window.location.href = "whatever"` it'll work. It might be something like a base tag intercepting it. Open your console on that specific page and type in that `window.location.href` code and hit enter, see if it redirects. If so, then your code is not reaching that line.

Comment: what JS framework is in use for eventing and routing? if you are not using a framework, you should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by changing `sucess` to `success` then try `window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";` or `window.location.href = "whatever"` or `window.location.replace("http://www.yoururl.com/");`

Then well you could add a return to it.
And if it doesn't still work? Try using a setTimeout.

Comment: Hurrul !!

Thank you, it worked !!
Thank you very much :)
You saved my life!

Sucess = fail
Success = correct

These times that the English I miss!